# Reading in a text file to display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, io

I am just working on a web site for fun and I was wondering if you could use JavaScript to read in a local text file and then display it HTML. So for example if I had a text file saved with my project then could I write a function in JavaScript that reads the entire file and then just displays all that text within on the web page?

I've looked around and tried to find something that will do this, but I don't think I fully understand. I have:

```
function readFile(fileName){
   var fileRead = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
   text = fileRead.OpenTextFile(fileName, 1, false, 0);

   while(!text.AtEndOfSteam){
       text += text.ReadLine();
    }

   text.Close();    
}
```

I don't know if this is will work or do what I want to do. So my question is, how do I use JavaScript to read in a text file, then display the contents of that text file on a webpage in HTML?

Comment: That is old and IE only. Look into FileReader

Answer (score 7):

You have to use the File API.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myFile");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

input.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var myFile = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
      output.textContent = e.target.result;
    });
    
    reader.readAsBinaryString(myFile);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myFile">

<div id="output"></div>
```

EDIT

After reading your comment, i think this is what you want.

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");

$("a").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax(this.href).done(function(data) {
    output.textContent = data;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>

<a href="link/to/file">Link to file</a>
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear. I have text files saved on my computer. I want it so that, say when someone clicks on a hyper link, that the text file is read and displayed on the page.

Comment: If you want someone to read a file on your computer, you can't do this in javascript. I think this is the best you can do only in html/javascript.

Comment: No. I want when someone clicks on a link it loads a text file that is included with the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reading file</title>
   </head>
<body>


<input type="file" id="myFile">
<hr>
<!--<div style="width: 300px;height: 0px" id="output"></div>-->
<textarea style="width:500px;height: 400px" id="output"></textarea>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("myFile");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

input.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var myFile = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
      output.textContent = e.target.result;
    });

    reader.readAsBinaryString(myFile);
  }
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```